# Fan out in DC convertors

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I know that **Fan out** is the maximum number of inputs that can be connected to a specific output. This limitation clearly affects data signals, but I don't know the case for power-supplying ICs.

I have a DC/DC step-down converter with an output of 1.8V, this output  is connected as an input to ***many* *ICs*** in a system for power supply. My question is this, should I consider the fan out in this case, or I have to calculate the max output power of my converter (Voltage and current) and simply see if it can power my ICs from datasheets?

Comment: The term "fan-out" doesn't really apply to power supplies. The procedure you need is straightforward.  I assume that you know how much current your DC-to-DC convertor can produce, so now you need to add up the maximum current of each IC that is powered by that convertor, and insure that it doesn't exceed your convertors capability.

Comment: So the term fan-out applies to data signals only. Right?

Comment: Well, it applies to a number of things. It applied to logic gates in the old 7400 series, before 74S adn 74LS made things more complicated. Today, it is mainly used with respect to the gates inside an FPGA or ASIC.

Comment: But for digital signals, like an enable from a microcontroller to many chips need to be enabled, does it applies?

Comment: Not any more. Since output drive current and input current consumption vary so wildly, your only option is to add them up from the information on the datesheets.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I think I am satisfied with your answers.

Comment: @Mark You should post your comments as an answer; they do a good job of answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "fan-out" doesn't really apply to power supplies. The procedure you need is straightforward. I assume that you know how much current your DC-to-DC convertor can produce, so now you need to add up the maximum current of each IC that is powered by that convertor, and insure that it doesn't exceed your convertors capability.

"Fan-out" originally applied to logic gates in the old 7400 series, before 74S and 74LS made things more complicated.

With all of the different semiconductor technologies used today, and because output drives and input currents can easily be tailored to the application, output drive current and input current consumption vary wildly. To know if your output has enough drive, you need to add up the required input currents and compare it with the output current of your source. You would need to do that for both source and sink (high and low) from the information in the datasheets.

Today, "fan-out" is mainly used with respect to the gates inside an FPGA or ASIC.